# Reshape THEN explode an array in a spark dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, split

I have a spark dataframe in the following format:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|            profiles|__record_timestamp__|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1...| 1651737406300000000|
|[1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0...| 1651736986300000000|
|[2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0...| 1651737232300000000|
|[1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0...| 1651737352300000000|
|[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1...| 1651737412300000000|
|[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1...| 1651737142300000000|
|[3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1...| 1651737574300000000|
|[2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1...| 1651737178300000000|
|[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1...| 1651737364300000000|
|[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0...| 1651737280300000000|
|[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0...| 1651737196300000000|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1...| 1651737436300000000|
|[8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3...| 1651737166300000000|
|[4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0...| 1651737538300000000|
|[1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0...| 1651737052300000000|
|[1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1...| 1651737082300000000|
|[1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0...| 1651737100300000000|
|[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0...| 1651736980300000000|
|[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0...| 1651737040300000000|
|[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1...| 1651737004300000000|
+--------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

The array in profiles is 91260 long. I need to first reshape it into 90*1024 arrays and then I plan to explode, each with an integer from 0-89 matching its place in the original array.

Any ideas how this can be done? f.explode() will only give me 1 element per column, split() only seems to work on strings, and I can't find a reshape, or array_split() function or anything. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by creating an array of the required [slices](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.slice.html) and then using [posexplode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode.html) function. For practicality I've created a smaller df to show how it works

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row

SPLIT_COUNT = 3
SPLIT_SIZE = 5
ARRAY_SIZE = SPLIT_COUNT * SPLIT_SIZE

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(profiles=list(range(ARRAY_SIZE)), timestamp=12345)
    ])

slices = [F.slice(F.col('profiles'), i * SPLIT_SIZE + 1, SPLIT_SIZE) for i in range(SPLIT_COUNT)]

df.select(
    F.posexplode(F.array(*slices)),
    F.col('timestamp')
).show()


+---+--------------------+---------+                                            
|pos|                 col|timestamp|
+---+--------------------+---------+
|  0|     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]|    12345|
|  1|     [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|    12345|
|  2|[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]|    12345|
+---+--------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [posexplode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode.html):

> ```
> from pyspark.sql import Row
> eDF = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, intlist=[1,2,3], mapfield={"a": "b"})])
> eDF.select(posexplode(eDF.intlist)).collect()
> [Row(pos=0, col=1), Row(pos=1, col=2), Row(pos=2, col=3)]
> ```

Comment: Not quite, because I don't want a new row for each element, I want one for each 1024 elements. There seems to be no function that takes col as an input as well as some integer for how to split the array in my column.

Comment: You may want to reword your question to make this clearer.